# How can I stop the item from getting published?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a eventreciever for item updates that have following method:

```
public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            base.ItemUpdated(properties);

            if (!HandleEvent(properties))
            {
                return;
            }

            var item = properties.ListItem;

            EventFiringEnabled = false;

            if (IsPublished(item))
            {       

            }

            EventFiringEnabled = true;

}
```

Here is the method for IsPublished:

```
private bool IsPublished(SPListItem item)
{
    return item.Level == SPFileLevel.Published;

}
```

I need to somhow stop it from publishing, how can I do that??

Answer (score 1):

```
public override void ItemCheckingIn(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
  base.ItemCheckingIn(properties);
  //Major Version
  if(..){
   properties.Cancel = true;
   properties.ErrorMessage = "you cannot publish!";
  }

 }
```